# How to stack(push) xPSR?

Tags: assembly, arm, stack, microcontroller

```
CMP    R1, R2
BLEQ   SUBROUTINE1
ADDEQ  R4, #5
```

I want that `ADDEQ` to be conditioned on the result of `CMP R1, R2`. However, if `SUBROUTINE1` modifies the `xPSR`, then I cannot get the desired behaviour. First thing that comes to my mind is pushing xPSR to the stack before calling the subroutine, and popping it at the return. However, when I want to do a

```
PUSH    {xPSR}
```

I get bad register symbol error(same for `PUSH {PSR}`). So, is not there a way to store the content of `xPSR` just as any other register?

Comment: psr is not any other register you can only push general purpose registers. you can perhaps copy the psr to a general purpose register and push that, you can use conditionals moveq r5,#1 ; movne r5,#0 and then compare on that after the call, etc...you can preserve r1 and r2 across the call (push them if you like) and then do the cmp after the call.  many solutions, but you can only push general purpose registers

Comment: please read the arm documentation before and while working with assembly language or the instruction set. look at the push and pop if listed as such or stm/ldm if the pseudo instructions push/pop are not documented for that architecture.

Comment: @old_timer actually, I read that xPSR is saved to interrupt stack when an interrupt occurs to preserve the current status of the program, which lead me to think that it could also be stacked in normal operation too.

Comment: @muyustan Why not simply swap the two instructions?  First do the addition, then the `BLEQ`?

Comment: Or, repeat the `CMP` later.

Comment: @ErikEidt yes, it is a solution, but my example was just to illustrate my point. The actual question is whetheter there is a way of pushing xPSR into stack or not. Apparently, there is not.

Comment: @muyustan yes but that is part of the interrupt/exception logic not a push instruction

Comment: r1 and r2 are volatile if this is the typical arm calling convention so you cant assume they retain their value you cant simply do the compare later, you can if you preserve them, thus the comment above.